# React Native: fastlane finished with errors

Tags: xcode, react-native, github-actions

I'm running CI/CD using github workflows and iOS build fails with this output:

```
[08:26:20]: 
[08:26:20]: ⬆️  Check out the few lines of raw `xcodebuild` output above for potential hints on how to solve this error
[08:26:20]:   For the complete and more detailed error log, check the full log at:
[08:26:20]:   /Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/<project name>-<project name>.log
[08:26:20]: 
[08:26:20]: Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
[08:26:20]: It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
[08:26:20]: to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
[08:26:20]: Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
[08:26:20]: sure your project is set up correctly.
[08:26:20]: fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
[08:26:20]: the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
[08:26:20]: Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[08:26:20]: 
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                  Lane Context                                   |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM          | ios                                                 |
| PLATFORM_NAME             | ios                                                 |
| LANE_NAME                 | ios export_ipa                                      |
| KEYCHAIN_PATH             | ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain              |
| ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_KEYCHAIN | "/Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db" |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
[08:26:20]: Error building the application - see the log above

+------+------------------------------+-------------+
|                 fastlane summary                  |
+------+------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                       | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform             | 0           |
| 2    | create_keychain              | 0           |
| 3    | import_certificate           | 0           |
| 4    | install_provisioning_profile | 0           |
| 5    | update_code_signing_settings | 0           |
| 6    | update_project_provisioning  | 0           |
| 7    | update_project_team          | 0           |
|    | build_app                    | 35          |
+------+------------------------------+-------------+

[08:26:20]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Error building the application - see the log above

#######################################################################
# fastlane 2.214.0 is available. You are on 2.213.0.
# You should use the latest version.
# Please update using `fastlane update_fastlane`.
#######################################################################
# Run `gem cleanup` from time to time to speed up fastlane
#######################################################################

2.214.0 Improvements
* [spaceship] fix olympus session request error after skipping 2FA Upgrade (#21317) via AbbyM (@AbbyM)
* [spaceship] add update method to ConnectAPI::User (#20956) via Vitalii Budnik (@nekrich)
* [supply][action] add `download_apk_from_google_play` action (and corresponding `supply` methods) (#21315) via Olivier Halligon (@AliSoftware)
* [docs] fix sync_code_signing.md (#21202) via Yuki Sakai (@VeyronSakai)
* [fastlane] fix fastlane action template warnings reported by Rubocop (#21310) via Bartosz Kosiorek (@BartoszKosiorek-TomTom)
* [docs][match] fix typos, improve wording, incorporate improvements to match documentation examples (#21302) via Roger Oba (@rogerluan)
* [match] fixes Gitlab Secure Files API limit (#21361) via Darby Frey (@darbyfrey)
* [match] adding access token prompt for GitLab Secure Files Match (#21279) via Darby Frey (@darbyfrey)
* [deliver] update upload_price_tier (#21282) via lukethoene (@lukethoene)

Please update using `fastlane update_fastlane`
Error: The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
```

I added step in workflow, which prints contents of the log file when job fails, and here's the output of log file:

```
Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode_14.2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace ios/<project name>.xcworkspace -scheme <project name> -configuration Debug -destination generic/platform=iOS -archivePath "/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-08-07/<project name> 2023-08-07 08.26.01.xcarchive" clean archive

User defaults from command line:
IDEArchivePathOverride = /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-08-07/<project name> 2023-08-07 08.26.01.xcarchive
IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES


** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

Prepare packages

Computing target dependency graph and provisioning inputs

Create build description
Build description signature: 355b340e896bdbd9dba987b5611ba068
Build description path: /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project name>-eyrioodbvepenugnskmjmdofbdnt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/<project name>/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/XCBuildData/355b340e896bdbd9dba987b5611ba068-desc.xcbuild

note: Building targets in dependency order
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNPermissions' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'react-native-google-maps' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNImageCropPicker' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNGestureHandler' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNBackgroundFetch' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNFBApp' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'react-native-webview' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'react-native-video' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNReanimated' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'react-native-geolocation' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'PromisesObjC' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'CocoaLumberjack' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'react-native-safe-area-context' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNCPushNotificationIOS' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNScreens' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNSoundPlayer' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNCAsyncStorage' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNBackgroundGeolocation' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'react-native-netinfo' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstallations' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'fmt' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/<project name>.xcodeproj: error: No profile for team '***' matching 'AppleDevelopment' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching '***/AppleDevelopment'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target '<project name>' from project '<project name>')
warning: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target '<project name>' from project '<project name>')
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target '<project name>' from project '<project name>')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target '<project name>' from project '<project name>')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNFBMessaging' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNCMaskedView' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'react-native-segmented-control' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNVectorIcons' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'RNImageCropPicker-QBImagePicker' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'react-native-slider' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseMessaging' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/<project name>-mobile/<project name>-mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'react-native-maps' from project 'Pods')
```

Any idea what might be a problem and how to solve it?